# Netbeans and Insubstantial

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, substance

I recently saw that there was an approach to integrate the Substance LAF with Netbeans that was abandoned in 2008. Now, the active development is made within the Insubstantial - project and since 2008, a lot of advances where made.

Everytime i see an article about Substance (and/or Flamingo) and Netbeans, the authors are using an outdated version of Substance, but not the new Insubstantial libraries.

Does someone know how to use them with Netbeans? The standard way by just adding the `--laf` parameter doesn't seem to work and i guess there wouldn't have been the integration project if it's that simple.

My target is to use a self-written `SubstanceSkin` with my Netbeans Platform application.

Kind regards,

David

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `-Dswing.defaultlaf` in `netbeans.conf`.

For example :

```
-Dswing.defaultlaf=org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel
```

Here is the [documentation](http://insubstantial.github.com/insubstantial/substance/docs/skins/toneddown.html) and the available skins.

Comment: netbeans.conf should accept -J-Dswingxxxx syntax for java options